# Compare parameter in WHERE clause stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedures which receives a list of ItemId's. If the list only contain one item this works:

```
AND (@OrgItemIds = -1 OR ...)
AND (@OrgItemIds = -1 AND...)
```

but if the list contains more than one item it crashes.

Anybody knows how to fix this? Can I check the size of the list somehow?
Or can I check just the first element of the list like @OrgItemIds[0] or something like that?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I've added the `sql-server` tag

Comment: If the list is received as a *relvar* then just JOIN to it. If it is not received as a *relvar*, then please explain further.

Comment: Instead of passing a comma separated list, pass a Table Value Parameter with each parameter in the list as a row.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "comma-separated set of values" or "array" datatypes in SQL SERVER. You handle the parameter as a scalar variable in your code. Thus when you provide a single value in that list, server implicitly converts it to int and your sp succeeds.
When you provide string with commas - it becomes impossible to convert it to int.

You have to manually parse your argument, put it into a table variable and then use this table in WHERE clause. Or change handling of this argument to support a string of values instead of scalar value:

```
... where @OrgItemIds like '%,' + cast(t.OrgItemIds as varchar(10)) + ',%'
```

which is much worse for performance than filtering by id or list of ids.